# Hall-effect pulse input to transistor for relay switching

Tags: transistors, relay, pulse

I have a Hall-effect sensor on a water flow meter. I want to switch a pump on when if there is flow (Hall-effect signal).

I was thinking of using a RC circuit on the base of my transistor that switches the relay for the pump when there are sufficient pulses from the Hall-effect sensor in the flow meter. I don't want a situation where the pump sporadically switches on at very low flow.

Something like this (ignore component values; I will set them when I experiment):

[image]

Any comments please if this would work.

Comment: You should always have a freewheel diode across the relay coil or your BJT might decide to go poof.

Comment: Pulse shape and go/nogo repetition frequency should be shown.

Comment: Thanks Andy  I checked the output from the hall effect last night and its a good square wave  -- I will have to check what the go no go freq is but my main area is will the RC circuit be able to hold the transistor ( which will depend on the frequency I decide to switch the relay on that I will determine experimentally with the physical system -- will the capacitor and Resistor (RC ) be able to hold the transistor on -- not sure if there could be some issue here -- going to test circuit this week and see what physically transpires

Comment: Thanks LUNDIN yes there will be a free wheeling for the back EMF as the relay shuts down Thanks

Comment: Good question. This question could be improved with a link to the datasheet for the specific Hall effect sensor.

Answer (score 0):

If you take only the edges of the square wave signal and rectify this derivative, you get a DC voltage that keeps the transistor on as long as the hall sensor frequency is high enough.
The component values are a suggested example for 10 Hz input frequency, which is typical for a simple flow meter.

The AC coupling guarantees, that the relay will turn off even if the flow meter stops with a final high level.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp2U15.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>